End all logged in sessions, before a user logs in on a browser
I am using Redash that contains multiple organizations. A single user can log into multiple organizations. I am using JWT Auth token to authenticate the user and redirect to specific orgainzation redash. I am able to login into other organization after I logout from one organization.
However, If I don't logout and close the browser and try to login to other organization, Redash is asking for username and password. But, it should login to the organization automatically.
Is there anything that can be done so that this scenario works?
User should be able to login even though earlier user didn't logout from an organization from the same browser.
